# Can we rebuke something?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I wonder if we can say rebuke something or not? According to the dictionaries, it seems that we can only rebuke someone but not something. I want to say something like "rebuke greed" in a formal text. I am confused.

The definition from Oxford Dictionary:

> Rebuke = ​the act of speaking severely to somebody because they have done
> something wrong

The definition from Cambridge Dictionary:

> Rebuke = to criticize someone strongly because you disapprove of what
> the person has said or done

The definition from Longman Dictionary:

> Rebuke = to speak to someone severely about something they have done wrong

The sentence, I want to use rebuke in:

> They rebuke his greed and present ethical arguments to argue why he
> should be punished.

In case this usage is wrong, could you please introduce me another suitable substitute? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of ***rebuke*** with inanimate nouns is archaic:

> archaic : to turn back or keep down - CHECK ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebuke))

It is used in this way in the Bible:

> <sup>***[KJV Psalm 106:9](https://biblehub.com/psalms/106-9.htm)***</sup> He ***rebuked*** *the Red sea* also, and it was dried up.

> <sup>***[KJV Luke 4:39](https://biblehub.com/luke/4-39.htm)***</sup> And he stood over her, and ***rebuked** the fever*; and it left her: and immediately she arose and ministered unto them.

It seems that this use has survived in modern writing, but it is [very rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rebuked%20his%20%2A_NOUN%2Crebuked%20his%20greed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crebuked%20his%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20disciples_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20brother_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20son_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20pupil_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20wife_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20servant_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20friends_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20fellow_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20companion_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brebuked%20his%20followers_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) and can be characterised as literary. Here are some instances:

> - Courts ***rebuke** the latest prosecutorial attack* on business. ([WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052970203711104577199412696071528))
> - Hours before the House vote, Nikki Haley, the U.S. ambassador to the U.N., ***rebuked** the report* as 'misleading'... (Slate Magazine, COHA)

One alternative would be the suggestion made by Trae. Another alternative would be to use transitive synonyms of *rebuke* which would accept an inanimate noun as their object, such as ***reprove*** which can mean:

> to express disapproval of : CENSURE
>
> - it is not for me to reprove popular taste
>   — D. W. Brogan ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprove))

Comment: It is probably a matter for discussion on Biblical Hermeneutics as to whether the Biblical rebukings involved spiritual agents giving rise to the natural disorders. Or rather as to how opinion divides here; they don't field unanswerable-for-now questions on BH either.

Answer (score 2):

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rebuke) entry says it is possible if that thing is an act:

> 2. To express sharp criticism regarding (an act, for example): "a series of sweeping decisions that rebuked the investigators'
>    presumptions" (Donald A. Ritchie).

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159286?rskey=JG2nbD&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) as well agrees that we may use it with 'something' if that something is a quality, action, etc.

> transitive. To find fault with, censure, condemn (a quality, action,
> etc.)
>
> 1875   B. Jowett in tr. Plato Dialogues (ed. 2) IV. 131   Parmenides
> rebukes this want of consistency in Socrates.
>
> 1960   C. Day Lewis
> Buried Day i. 22   All would rebuke my naughtiness with a mild ‘Ah,
> don't be so bold, Master Cecil.’
>
> 2005   Providence (Rhode Island)
> Jrnl. (Nexis) 4 Apr. a7   We can ask schools to ‘handle’ these
> matters, and we can praise or rebuke their actions.

The examples above all refer to specific instances or qualities of specific people.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in your question, you must rebuke a person about something.

> They rebuke ***him for*** his greed and present ethical arguments to argue why he should be punished.